# Angular 2 router - appends url rather than navigate to main

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following configuration:

Main navigation with 2 links:

```
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/first']" first </a>
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/second']"> second </a>
```

And in the First component I have a "details" link:

```
<div [routerLink]="['/detail', item.id]">
```

My app.routing.ts:

```
{path: 'first', component: FirstComponent},
{path: 'second', component: SecondComponent},
{path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent }
```

In the First component when navigating to /detail:item everything works fine.
However when I try to hit the B link from the main navigation I get a wrong URL.
So basically it is:

1) Goto First component      >>>     localhost/First

2) Goto item details         >>>     localhost/detail/someId

3) Try to go to Second component (localhost/Second) >>> but it is localhost/detail/Second (and every other click on item detail appends another "/detail" to the url, so we get /detail/detail/Second, etc.. )

I tried it and without the '/' but the effect is the same.
I found out that if I add useHash:true to the routing everything works as expected.

```
 export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash:true});
```

However I don't want to have the hash.

My question is - why this is working with the hash and doesn't without. Also how can I fix the appending issue. And any general explanations about the routing will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I dont see any issue with the routes, Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z2VhLta6mxqgBtnnGg1P?p=preview), Can you update it to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

Problem was that I was using {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './'} (with a dot)
rather than {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}. Removing the dot fixed it.